# Show that $|f(z)+f(-z)+f(iz)+f(-iz)| \le 4|z|^4$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be a holomorphic function, with $f(0)=0$. Prove that $$ |f(z)+f(-z)+f(iz)+f(-iz)| \le 4|z|^4$$ for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$.

I tried [Schwarz Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) but i get $4|z|$, which is missing the power. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the Schwarz Lemma to each term separately gives not the
intended result because the special symmetry of the problem is lost.

Instead, define
$$
 g(z) = \frac 14 (f(z)+f(-z)+f(iz)+f(-iz))
$$
and observe that the power series of $g$ contains only powers of
$z^4$, so that
$$
 g(z) = h(z^4)
$$
for some holomorphic function $h: \Bbb D \to \Bbb D$ with $h(0) = 0$.
Now apply the Schwarz Lemma to $h$.

This can be generalized to
$$
 |f(z) + f(\omega z) + \ldots + f(\omega^{N-1}z)| \le N |z|^N
$$
where $N \in \Bbb N$ and $\omega = e^{2\pi i/N}$ is the $N^{\text{th}}$
root of unity.